# -[__NSCFString setLineWidth:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I am running my application I am getting the following exception:

> [__NSCFString setLineWidth:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15b1ae00

and the app is crashing.
If I create a `UIBezierPath`, it works, but when I have the same `UIBezierPath` shared from other user, it crashes.

```
<UIBezierPath: 0x175005a0; <MoveTo {250, 466}>,
<CurveTo {268, 344} {246, 453} {247, 440}>,
<MoveTo {268, 344}>,
<CurveTo {271, 327} {271, 332} {271, 323}>,
<MoveTo {271, 327}>,
<CurveTo {273, 360} {271, 336} {272, 346}>,
<MoveTo {273, 360}>,
<CurveTo {295, 379} {282, 381} {287, 383}>,
<MoveTo {295, 379}>,
<CurveTo {312, 337} {302, 363} {308, 347}>,
<MoveTo {312, 337}>,
<CurveTo {324, 316} {317, 323} {320, 320}>,
<MoveTo {324, 316}>,
<CurveTo {343, 295} {330, 311} {336, 303}>,
<MoveTo {343, 295}>,
<CurveTo {356, 276} {348, 289} {355, 278}>
```

The only difference is 0x175005a0. How Can I solve it?

Comment: I know where it crashes, at  line: [path1 setLineWidth:1.5]; What I do NOT know is why?

Comment: You either have a memory management problem or the shared UIBezierPath is actually a NSString.

Comment: Show your code. It's hard to know what's wrong.

Comment: It crashes because path1 is an NSString*, We don't know _why_ it is an NSString*, but it clearly is one

Comment: What code is involved in the "shared from other user" part?

Comment: NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]  length:[webData length]
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSPropertyListSerialization
                          propertyListWithData:[theXML dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                          options:kNilOptions
                          format:NULL
                          error:NULL];

Comment: *dict  {
    arrPaths =     (
        "<UIBezierPath: 0x1702a4560; <MoveTo {287, 473.5}>,\n <CurveTo {544, 272.5} {298.5, 464} {417.5, 396}>",
    );
    colores =     (
        0
    );
    indiceCompas =     (
        1
    );
}